# Scroll table dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intel-xdk

I load a table dynamically with data. I give each row  a unique ID. When you click on a row to edit data a separate editable table is filled with data from row selected. Once data is saved the next row is automatically selected. As you progress saving each row I want initial table to scroll row selected into view. Using bootstrap frame work and Intel XDK 3400. I have tried numerous examples I located on web (appear to be for web applications) some give errors others I do not get a error but table does not scroll. I have tried using ROW ID and ROW number with no success. The scenario I am working on is for a android build.

Answer (score 0):

//var rw is the row number of row selected form initial table

```
rw = rw + 1;
var rowm = mytable1.rows[rw];
var rid = rowm.id;
var moveto = document.getElementById(rid);  
moveto.scrollIntoView(true);
```

thought I had tried this before - however it works now